Why does group play equalize a lottery's actual Expected Value to the effective Expected Value?
My boss acknowledges that "the expected value of buying a ticket is negative, or that winning is so unlikely that buying a ticket is a bad investment." But she still wants me to join the lottery office pool. As supporting evidence, she cites

My advice to players is to never buy Lotto Max and Lotto 649 tickets on their own. The effective expected value is very low. But for group play, the only games groups should play are Lotto Max and Lotto 649. The larger than average jackpots results in an expected value much larger than average. Given the jackpot is shared, the actual expected value is equal to the effective expected value.

Here are odds and payouts for Lotto Max and Lotto 649.
I understand just the first 3 sentences.
I know what expected value (EV) is, but
what's ACTUAL EV??? EFFECTIVE EV???
Why does Group Play make the actual EV = the effective EV?

Don't put so much text in the links. And those links look scammy.

@ThomasAndrews how do I improve post? the first link is to another post here - no scam. I can't delete the second - that's the basis for question. the third and fourth links are from official lottery - no scam.

No amount of tickets bought, group or alone, have a positive expected value. There is no advantage to a group strategy.

The second link goes to an essentially blank page. But the first thing to do is remove all that text from the link. Link on a few words.

The text, as written, is basically nonsense.
Here are a few things that might relate to what it is trying to communicate:

The expected value of any lottery ticket is exactly equal to $\sum \mathrm{payout} \times P(\mathrm{payout}) - \mathrm{cost}$.

If you buy multiple tickets, your expected value is the sum of the EVs of the individual tickets.

Buying a ticket as an individual has a high variance in payout - with a very high probability the payout is that you lose the money you spent on it, and with a very small probability you win a lot of money.

Buying into a group ticket or a syndicate reduces this variance, since the probability of at least one of the tickets winning is higher but in return the payout is shared among the members of the group.

Therefore, in terms of utility, the group ticket may be a better choice than the individual ticket. In particular, if winning $\frac{1}{N}$ of the jackpot is more than $\frac{1}{N}$ as good for you as winning the whole jackpot, then the group ticket has better utility.

With that said, the probability of winning with a group ticket is still incredibly small - you might be going from a 1 in 14,000,000 chance to win \$5,000,000 to a 1 in 1,400,000 chance to win \$500,000. And the EV is still going to be essentially the same in either case (and will still be negative except in the rarest of circumstances).


